# Reply on bot mention

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a simple code that should reply when someone mentions the bot.

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "<@935849545789763585>" || '<@!935849545789763585>') {
      message.channel.send('Hi');
  }
});
```

But I have a problem because the bot is replying multiple times.

[image: here proof]

Comment: You really want to have `if(message.author.bot) return;` in your code as well, otherwise the bot will respond to itself creating an endless loop of messages

Answer (score 2):

I see you're trying to check if the message content is `<@935849545789763585>` (mentioning your bot). (You should use [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/MessageMentions) by the way.)

The issue is with your if condition.

```js
message.content === "<@935849545789763585>" || '<@!935849545789763585>'
```

When you mention your bot, the first condition passes, as it should. When the first condition fails, the `OR` operator will check if the second condition is true, in this case, `'<@!935849545789763585>'` will ALWAYS be true since it is not an empty string and is not comparing anything.

Your if statement is basically evaluated like this:

```js
message.content === "<@935849545789763585>" || true
```

The solution is to just remove the second condition.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "<@935849545789763585>") {
        message.channel.send("Hi");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `if (message.content === "<@935849545789763585>" || '<@!935849545789763585>')` always returns `true`. It doesn't matter what the value of `message.content` is because `'<@!935849545789763585>'` is a truthy value. Check out the snippet below:

```js
let message = { content: false }
if (message.content === "<@935849545789763585>" || "<@!935849545789763585>") {
  console.log(true)
}
```

As your if statement is incorrect, you send a new message every single time there is an incoming message.

You could check the `mentions` instead:

```js
if (message.mentions.members.has(client.user.id)) {
  message.channel.send('Hi');
}
```

Or:

```js
if (message.mentions.members.has('3584954578976358')) {
  message.channel.send('Hi');
}
```